# Parallel memcpy in cpp

Tags: c++, multithreading, pointers, c++14, memcpy

I am trying to copy a matrix in parallel.  Below is the code that I am working with.  Currently, it works as expected with char, but it seg faults when I use shorts.  I assume that the bug is in copying outside of the memory outside of the vector.  I have tried to debug my assumption without success.

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0)
project(memcpy CXX)
find_package (Threads)
add_executable(memcpy main.cpp)
set_property(TARGET memcpy PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 17)
target_link_libraries (memcpy ${CMAKE_THREAD_LIBS_INIT})
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cassert>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <mutex>
#include <string>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>


class Barrier {
  public:
    explicit Barrier(std::size_t const count) : m_threshold(count), m_remaining(count), m_generation(0) {}

    void wait() {
        auto local = std::unique_lock<std::mutex>{m_mutex};
        auto current_generation = m_generation;

        m_remaining--;
        if (!m_remaining) {
            m_generation++;
            m_remaining = m_threshold;
            m_condition.notify_all();
        } else {
            m_condition.wait(local, [this, current_generation] { return current_generation != m_generation; });
        }
    }

  private:
    std::mutex m_mutex;
    std::condition_variable m_condition;
    std::size_t m_threshold;
    std::size_t m_remaining;
    std::size_t m_generation;
};


template <typename T>
class Matrix {
    using reference = typename std::vector<T>::reference;
    using const_reference = typename std::vector<T>::const_reference;

  public:
    Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols) : m_rows(rows), m_cols(cols), m_data(m_cols * m_rows) {}
    Matrix(std::size_t rows, std::size_t cols, T const& default_val) : m_rows(rows), m_cols(cols), m_data(m_cols * m_rows, default_val) {}

    constexpr std::size_t get_columns() const { return m_cols; }
    constexpr std::size_t get_rows() const { return m_rows; }
    constexpr std::size_t get_element_count() const {
        assert(m_cols * m_rows == m_data.size());
        return m_cols * m_rows;
    }

    T* data() { return m_data.data(); }
    T const* data() const { return m_data.data(); }

    reference operator()(std::size_t const column_x, std::size_t const row_y) {
        assert(0 <= column_x);
        assert(column_x < get_columns());
        assert(0 <= row_y);
        assert(row_y < get_rows());

        return m_data[row_y * m_cols + column_x];
    }

    const_reference operator()(std::size_t const column_x, std::size_t const row_y) const {
        assert(0 <= column_x);
        assert(column_x < get_columns());
        assert(0 <= row_y);
        assert(row_y < get_rows());

        return m_data[row_y * m_cols + column_x];
    }

  private:
    std::size_t const m_rows;
    std::size_t const m_cols;
    std::vector<T> m_data;
};


static_assert(false, "FIX ME");
using T = char;
// using T = short;
// using T = int;
// using T = double;


void run(std::size_t const my_rank, std::size_t const num_threads, Barrier& barrier, Matrix<T> const& from_data, Matrix<T>& to_data) {
    auto n = from_data.get_element_count();
    std::string str;

    if (my_rank == 0) {
        std::cerr << "bytes to copy: " << (n * sizeof(T)) << '\n';
    }

    // initialization
    std::size_t segment_size = n / num_threads;
    std::size_t start = (my_rank * segment_size) * sizeof(T);
    std::size_t end = ((my_rank + 1) * segment_size) * sizeof(T);
    std::size_t distance = end - start;


    str += "  my_rank: " + std::to_string(my_rank);
    str += "  segment_size: " + std::to_string(segment_size);
    str += "  start: " + std::to_string(start);
    str += "  end: " + std::to_string(end);
    str += "  distance: " + std::to_string(distance);
    str += "  rank: " + std::to_string(my_rank);
    str += "  start: " + std::to_string(start);
    str += "  end: " + std::to_string(end);
    str += "  distance: " + std::to_string(distance);
    str += "  e: " + std::to_string(start + distance);
    str += "\n";
    std::cerr << str;

    barrier.wait();
    std::memcpy(to_data.data() + start, from_data.data() + start, distance);
    barrier.wait();


    if (my_rank == 0)
        for (auto y = 0; y < from_data.get_rows(); y++) {
            for (auto x = 0; x < from_data.get_columns(); x++) {
                if (to_data(x, y) != from_data(x, y)) {
                    std::cerr << "x: " << x << '\t' << "y: " << y << "\t\t";
                    std::cerr << "to: " << to_data(x, y) << '\t' << "from: " << from_data(x, y) << '\n';
                }
            }
        }

    barrier.wait();
}


int main() {
    auto const num_threads = 1;
    // auto const num_threads = 4;

    // auto const width = 64;
    // auto const height = 64;
    auto const width = 97;
    auto const height = 101;

    auto from_data = Matrix<T>(width, height, 70);
    auto to_data = Matrix<T>(width, height, 84);

    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    auto barrier = Barrier{num_threads};
    for (auto i = 0; i < num_threads; i++) {
        threads.emplace_back(run, i, num_threads, std::ref(barrier), std::ref(from_data), std::ref(to_data));
    }

    for (auto& thread : threads) {
        thread.join();
    }
}
```

Comment: I doubt you will get a significant performance improvement from threads if your goal is just to duplicate data in memory... maybe if you use a number of threads equal to the number of memory channels but even so, CPU clocks are already about the double the memory's, which makes it four times faster considering you have to read and then write back, the memory bus is the bottleneck here, not the CPU.

Comment: `auto from_data = Matrix<std::string>(width, height, 70);` -- Your code is instantly broken.  If you had considered things like this, you would have never used `memcpy`.  Never use `std::memcpy` if there is a chance that the thing you're copying could be non-POD.  Compilers these days are smart enough to choose what type of copy to use when you use `std::copy` instead (either memcpy, a loop, etc.).

Comment: @Havenard The threads already exist at this point in the code and would have nothing to do but wait around for the memcpy to finish. (it's also for a university assignment)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> `std::memcpy(to_data.data() + start, from_data.data() + start, distance)`

`std::vector<T>::data()` returns a `T*` so if you add an integral value `foo` to it, you effectively add `foo * sizeof T` bytes ... but you allready multiplied with `sizeof(T)` earlier when calculating `start` and `end`. Also, `std::memcpy()` won't work for `T`s that are not PODs.

Better use `std::copy()`.

Comment: Also, `std::copy` is written to be smart enough to fall back to `std::memcpy` or equivalent if the type that is detected is trivially copyable.  So you're not losing anything by using `std::copy`.